# Prove that ∼∼P ⊢P (Sider)

Tags: logic

2.4(c)

1. ∼∼P                    premise .
2. ∼∼P →(∼P →∼∼P)         PL1 .
3. ∼P→∼∼P                 1,2,MP .
4. (∼P →∼∼P)→((∼P →∼P)→P) PL3 .
5. (∼P→∼P)→P              3,4,MP .
6. ∼P→∼P                  premise 2.4(b) .
7. P                      5,6,MP .

This is the answer, what I don't understand is line 6 when it says ~P->~P is a premise according to 2.4(b).

Here is the answer to 2.4(b)

We need to prove that ⊢(∼P →P)→P

1. ∼P →((∼P →∼P)→∼P)→ etc.     PL2
2. ∼P →((∼P →∼P)→∼P)           PL1
3. (∼P →(∼P →∼P))→(∼P →∼P)     1,2,MP
4. ∼P→(∼P→∼P)                  PL1
5. ∼P→∼P                       3,4 MP
6. (∼P →∼P)→(∼P →P)→P          PL3
7. (∼P→P)→P                    5,6,MP

So, I see that in line 5 that it's the same as in line 6. What I don't understand is how you're able to cite a completely different proof. If I didn't have 2.4(b), how would I be able to continue the proof from line 5 in 2.4(c)?

The axioms are defined as:

1. P->(Q->P)                    PL1
2. (P->(Q->X))->(P->Q)->(P->X)) PL2
3. (~Q->~P)->((~Q->P)->Q)       PL3

Comment: How is your axiom PL3 _defined_?

Comment: Hi @Henning Makholm, thanks for replying I added the edits to the post

Comment: Are you really sure the last $P$ in your PL3 should not be a $Q$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you're right! it's supposed to be a Q

Comment: thanks @HenningMakholm for noticing that

Comment: You say "Why is it ((P->~P)->P)?" ... but I don't see that statement anywhere ...

Comment: @Bram28 You're totally right, I think I miswrote the problem and got confused. I actually have another quick question that I just can't wrap my head around. I went ahead and edited the description so that it'd make more sense. Do you happen to have any ideas on how line 5 works in 2.4(c)?

Comment: Line 5 of 2.4(c) is  " (∼P→∼P)→P" which is said to be  the consequent  C of a modus ponens whose antecedent, A, is (presumably) the formula in line 3—namely  " (∼P→∼∼P)".  For the modus ponens to work Line 4 should therefore be "A→C", which, in fact, it is.

Comment: thank you @lonzaleggiera ! very much appreciated!

Comment: I believe author actually meant "premise 2.4$(a)$", since excercise 2.4$(a)$ asks us to show that $\vdash P \rightarrow P$, and thus substituting $P$ by ~$P$ gives ~$P \rightarrow$~$P$.

Answer (score 1):

First, line 5) from 2.4c is nothing more than MP applied to lines 3) and 4), as indicated. That is, MP is defined as:

$\varphi \to \psi$

$\varphi$

$\therefore \psi$

In this partiuclar case, line 3) is the $\varphi$. That is, use $\varphi= \neg P \to \neg \neg P$

Line 5) is the $\psi$. That is: $\psi= (\neg P \to \neg P) \to P$

And line 4) is the $\varphi \to \psi$, i.e. $(\neg P \to \neg \neg P) \to ((\neg P \to \neg P) \to P)$

Second, if you didn't have the proof for 2.4b, then after line 5) you would simply repeat the very 7 lines from the proof of 2.4b, so these would become lines 6 through 12, where line 12 would be $(\neg P \to P) \to P$

And then what is now line 7 becomes line 13

Comment: thank you @Bram28 ! i really appreciate it